# Identify this Italian sport

Tags: international-sports

I am trying to recall the name of a sport with the following details:

1. The match I saw was between two Italian sides and I believe it had an Italian name.
2. It is similar to football, although I believe the hands were used also.
3. It was played on a sandy surface in an enclosed pitch (waist-level fencing).
4. The game was very violent and bloody, with punching and kicking opponents allowed.
5. It's **not** the Fighting Football League.
6. It seemed perhaps to be steeped in historical tradition.
7. It may only be contested between two cities/teams.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sounds like [Calcio Fiorentino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calcio_Fiorentino)

> Just like Roman harpastum, it was played in teams of 27, using both feet and hands. Goals could be scored by throwing the ball over a designated spot on the perimeter of the field. The **playing field is a giant sand pit** with a goal running the width of each end. There is a main referee, six linesmen and a field master. Each game is played out for 50 minutes with the winner being the team with the most points or 'cacce'.
>
> The modern version allows tactics such as head-butting, punching, elbowing, and choking, but forbids sucker punching and kicks to the head.[5]

Comment: That is exactly it, thank you! Did you know of it previously or did you research it?  I couldn't get a google result at all!

Comment: I was googling for lists of sports in Italy and found one called "sferistici."  Googling for that lead me to a Yahoo Answer about Italian sports in the 1500's which included a link to Calcio Fiorentino.