# What's the name of the sport that has people on bicycles flipping a football with their wheels?

Tags: international-sports

I swear I saw this on Transworld Sport about twenty years ago. It was a tennis-like game, using a football (soccer) ball. The players had to stay on their bikes, doing wheelies to catch the ball and flick it back.

I've never seen it since. The closest I could find was more like polo (with bikes and footballs).

Surely someone else has seen it?

(I wanted to create tags sport-identification and obscure, but don't have the points.)

Comment: Another sport that includes bicycles and a ball is [cycle ball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_ball). However, in this sport the the ball is not played over the net, either. (Similarly as in [cycle polo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_polo), which you have mentioned.)

Comment: You wrote: *I wanted to create tags sport-identification and obscure, but don't have the points.* Creation of a tag for identifying some sport was discussed [here](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3002/what-is-this-three-against-one-game-with-red-and-blue-balls#comment6032_3002). See also the meta-thread linked in the comments there. The questions of this type, which I have seen, were tagged ([tag:international-sports]).

Comment: I don´t exactly know, but can you write something like cycle net or cycle tennis?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I could find on the web was "Bicycle Football" something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WfFlcCe6LDA).