# Which sport is played on this field?

Tags: trivia, international-sports, venues, futsal

I have an [extension in my web browser](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/earth-view-from-google-ea/bhloflhklmhfpedakmangadcdofhnnoh) that brings up an aerial photo from different parts of the world each time I open a new tab. A couple of days ago it was an image from Tokyo (I think), with a kind of sports field that I haven't seen before. I'm not able to find that image now, as the browser extension only remembers the last 10 or so images.

Here's how I remember it:

[image: Some sports field]

It could have been a soccer field, if the penalty area didn't have rounded corners. Also, I am unable to say anything about the dimensions of the field.

What sport is played here?

Comment: Welcome to Sports SE. I tagged with `international-sports` as we have had "sport identification" questions tagged with this before ([example 1](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3002/what-is-this-three-against-one-game-with-red-and-blue-balls), [example 2](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/870/identify-this-italian-sport)).

Comment: @MASTERMIND_ED: I see you added the `international-sports` tag. But could it be that it is a sport mostly played in Japan?

Comment: Sure, but we don't know that until we identify it. I placed a "suitable" tag based on how we have handled such questions in the past.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One place this type of field can be found is at the [Tokyo Metropolitan Gymnasium](https://www.google.com/maps/place/%E6%9D%B1%E4%BA%AC%E4%BD%93%E8%82%B2%E9%A4%A8%E9%99%B8%E4%B8%8A%E7%AB%B6%E6%8A%80%E5%A0%B4/@35.6784145,139.7124318,364a,20y,270h/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0000000000000000:0x63cd3c3aad039129!8m2!3d35.6785202!4d139.7122074!6m1!1e1), which includes a [futsal court](https://www.tef.or.jp/tmg/en_coat_top.jsp) that is consistent with your findings.

> Which sport is played on this field?

[Futsal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futsal), a variant of football/fùtbol (also known as soccer in the US).

[image: futsal field]

Comment: You are right! Now that I know I was looking at a futsal court, I was able to find back to the image I had been looking at. It was indeed the [Adidas Futsal Park](https://www.google.no/maps/place/Adidas+Futsal+Park/@35.6587108,139.7005974,172m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x60188b57f2c00001:0x1f9914a8f3bf2609!8m2!3d35.6587073!4d139.7007901?hl=no).